# Swipe buttons just like lock unlock buttons

Tags: android

I want to develop swipe buttons just like we see for lock unlock function on android idle screen.

Is these widgets are provided by android or we need to create them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget's name is RotarySelector. It is designated as an internal widget so you cant use it directly. But if you really want it you can always get the source code and stick it in your app.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's a custom view. The images behind that sliders can be found in the android sdk folder under platforms, as far as I remember, may that gives you another hint to search for.